How to fix a Safe created on BSC using replay tx with wrong master copy 1.1.1 from Ethereum?
We had a Gnosis Safe on Ethereum and our finance manager replayed the tx on BSC so we could access funds send to the wrong network. When he replayed the tx, it used a master copy address for 1.1.1 that does not exist on BSC.
This is the create tx that was replayed: https://bscscan.com/tx/0xe9a8c31231fb697703d5c12a3f988abec1d0bd10431936e65a65e072fb5dc6df
You can see the master copy address used was 0x34CfAC646f301356fAa8B21e94227e3583Fe3F5F, which does not exist on BSC.
It should have used the address: 0x76E2cFc1F5Fa8F6a5b3fC4c8F4788F0116861F9B
How do I go about fixing this Safe? Can I call a function to update the master copy to the correct one?

Short answer is no, it will not be possible to update the master copy from a deployed Safe, as it is the contract used to create the Safe. But good news is that it seems that both addresses you mentioned for master copy do exist in BSC. They may not be from official deployments, but it still seems that the correct contracts were deployed there. I could also see that the safe seems to load correctly on Safe Wallet UI; is there anything not functioning correctly with your safe? Why do you want to "fix" it? Thanks in advance for your answers  Best, Louis

It loads for you on BSC? It works fine on Ethereum as that was the original deployment.

Could you guys create the 1.1.1 master copy at the address 0x34CfAC646f301356fAa8B21e94227e3583Fe3F5F
I see others have done the same thing expecting that same mastercopy to exist, but it does not

@Louis-SafeCoreTeam Can you please let me know on above

Yes it loads correctly on BSC: https://app.safe.global/home?safe=bsc:0x5d0f1d5dd45ea4c1ba7b93e2c2407457fafebe91 No need to deploy the master copy as it is already deployed at this address!

@Louis-SafeCoreTeam It says This Safe Account couldn't be loaded when I clicked your link.

Also, this address is not a contract on BSC 0x34CfAC646f301356fAa8B21e94227e3583Fe3F5F

Apologies, there were some inaccuracies in my previous comments: the Safe does not load correctly and the 1.1.1 contract is not deployed at 0x34CfAC646f301356fAa8B21e94227e3583Fe3F5F; I am looking internally at solutions to deploy v1.1.1 on BSC at this address. Please hang tight while we are working on it
